# How to allow write access (create/write files) to a directory but prevent delete (to all, including owner)

Tags: permissions

I want to allow any write access to directory but prevent ANYONE (aside from root?) from deleting the files once they are written.  Is there a permissions system that would allow for this?

There is no time to modify permissions between write and delete time.

Comment: I've been looking into chattr and the "undeletable" attribute...

Comment: Was there any solution for this question? I was kind of curious myself. I would like to create a directory that can be written to by anyone but once something is written it can only be deleted by root. Even the user is the owner. No Modify. Is this kind of customization possible on just a standard debian install? Any response would be **appreciated**.

Comment: Immutable `+i` flag on the file and append `+a` on the containing directory might point you in the right direction.  Don't know how to automatically set it on file create though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chattr +a` seems to work as it only allows append to the directory (creating files)

Root won't be able to remove it directly but is able to `chattr -a` when it comes time to delete.

Comment: This does not work on a mounted file system.

Comment: It depends on your filesystem and whether it has support for these attributes.  Should work under ext2/3/4 and perhaps others

Answer (score 1):

Root will always have permissions.

chmod +t file/folder

This sets a sticky bit so only the creator of the file can delete it, no-one else. Outside of that you may need to explore other options, such as making the app/person run the create command as : sudo -u USER vi/touch /dir/file

Also check out the chmod manpage